# How to notify a component of an operation made by another?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to use this [link's](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction) approach to notify a component of an operation made on another component. It suggests adding a `Subject` variable in a service, call the `next()` method and subscribe to it from the component that needs to be notified.

The problem is that the subscribe method pointing to `Subject<number>.asObservable()` is not firing.

The scenario is: Form component adds a row using the `TasklistResourcesService`, then after the Http post, the Form component shows a notification and the service would 'indirectly' notify the Grid component that a row has been added.

Form component:

```
submit({ value, valid }: { value: FormGroup, valid: boolean }) {
    if (value['userId']) {
      this.tasklistResourcesService.addResource(this.tasklist, +value['userId'])
        .subscribe(response => {
          if (response) {
            this.notification.success('Sucesso!', 'Cadastro realizado.');
          } else {
            this.notification.error('Erro!', 'Cadastro não realizado.');
          }
        },
        (err) => console.log(err));
    }
```

TasklistResourcesService

```
private resourceAddedSource = new Subject<number>();

  resourceAdded$ = this.resourceAddedSource.asObservable();

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

addResource(tasklistId: number, userId: number) {
    const observable = this.http
      .post<TasklistResource>(`${this.baseUrl}/${tasklistId}/resources`, {
        tasklistId: tasklistId,
        userId: userId
      }, { observe: 'response' }).share();

    observable.subscribe(response => {
      this.resourceAddedSource.next(userId);
    });

    return observable;
  }
```

Grid component

```
subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private tasklistResourcesService: TasklistResourcesService,
    private notification: NotificationsService,
    private confirmation: ConfirmationService
  ) {
    this.subscription = tasklistResourcesService.resourceAdded$.subscribe(
      user => {
        this.refreshGrid();  // THIS ISN'T BEING CALLED
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: is the service a singleton?

Comment: Actually it isn't. I missed that point.

Comment: Added the service to the providers attribute of the parent component only and now it is working. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad to hear it was "an easy fix" :)